# How to forward geocode in Python without Internet connection from scripts?

Tags: python, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I have addresses I want to convert into latitudes and longitudes. I do not have admin rights on my computer, so Python scripts cannot connect to the geocoding APIs (i.e. Google, Nominatim, etc.). I have tried the geocoding packages available on PyPi.

Do you all know of any alternative to connecting directly to the API? Is there anyway to do offline geocoding? I have seen packages for offline reverse geocoding, but not for forward geocoding. Logically, the only option I can think of is to download the data en masse and compare locally. I'm not sure the feasibility of that though.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: You can send HTTP requests without admin rights.

Comment: Would it be possible to post a simple example of such a request that I could test in a script? I haven't been able to make it work for this or other projects. I get errors such as "getaddrinfo failed".

Comment: That looks like a problem with your system's configuration.

Comment: Is there a direction you could point me to try to figure that issue out? This is a work laptop, so I'm not sure how much configuration I will be able to do.

Comment: Using the command line to 'ping google.com' results in "could not find host". So I believe it is a network restriction. I also can't install Python packages directly from the Internet.

Comment: How many have you to convert?

Comment: Not that many (16K) initially), but it's something that we are looking to implement into our work stream on a dynamic basis, so there will be demand to do more later. I know I could run the current ones through an API through a browser, but that isn't sustainable.

Comment: It appears to me that your company should run a simple web page that does nothing more than provide the needed information for each of those 16,000 addresses. Table look-up. If someone in the field queries for an unavailable address then there's always Google as a fall-back. A frill would be to arrange to save that address, do the look-up as a background task and update the table.

Comment: This isn't an option based on the company - but thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Why was I downvoted? Very new to SO, so please let me know what I can do to remedy the loss in reputation.

Answer (score 1):

`geopy` could be what you want.

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim()
>>> location = geolocator.geocode('1327 Harding Place, Charlotte, North Caroline')
>>> location.latitude, location.longitude
(35.2082683450311, -80.8377261377877)
```

Available at https://github.com/geopy/geopy or http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ if the laptop runs Windows.

EDIT: I just saw your last comment. Copy the `.whl` file that downloads from that second link (assuming you're running Windows) to a CD or DVD and install from that.

Comment: I tried `geopy`, as well as the other geocoding Python packages. They all require connection to the API through a URL. That's the crux of my issue - how to geocode without that connection.

Comment: Thanks for the install tip! I can install the packages just fine by downloading the .whl files (I can connect to the Internet via my browser, just not via scripts, command line, etc.). Unfortunately, the packages still require that URL connection when run.

Comment: You must know *this*: Highlight the address, for instance the one in my answer. Right-click and select Google. Click on the map in the search results. On the marker for the address, right-click and select 'what's here'. Works for small numbers of queries.

Comment: Thank you - that's definitely an option for small numbers. Unfortunately, I don't think we have the patience to do that for 16K queries!

Comment: Made me laugh when I saw that number.